# Execution plan for slow running stored procedure

Tags: sql, stored-procedures

I have posted my estimated execution plan here,
https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=rk6Z6MKxf

Can anyone help me to find out why my stored procedure is running very slow?

Comment: I suggest you paste your code here and also the part of the code that involves that stored procedure you are mentioning. You have to narrow it down the problem.

Answer (score 0):

So many index scan in your execution plan, I think you must add index or optimize your join after examine your execution plan to get index seek (at least).

Comment: Thank you for your reply. add index means create indexes on all tables is it? And how to optimize joins to get index seek ? Can you explain a bit? I am not very good in SQL